# Difference between “Class ” and “Classes”

Tags: grammar

Is this statement true?
"Parents send their children to English class"
Or should I use "classes"?

Comment: That statement is true. It would still be true if you used "classes", but with a slightly different meaning. That said, it's most likely you want to use "class" (singular, instead of "classes" (plural).

Comment: To my ear, singular ***class*** strongly suggests a non-native speaker usage here. But perhaps I'm biased, because I think plural ***classes*** more weakly carries the same implication. The natural word for me here is ***lessons***, where I don't suppose anyone would use the singular.

Comment: thanx a lot,but how can I use "lessons" in this structure?  parents send their children to English lessons??

Comment: @FumbleFingers My first thought was that 'class' and 'classes' are American. And I would have agreed that we are more inclined to call them 'lessons' but for the fact that I recently told someone that my grandson goes to a gymnastics class on Mondays. My sense now is that 'lesson' implies one-to-one tuition, such as a 'piano lesson'. Where there is a group I feel more inclined to say 'class'.

Comment: @WS2: I only posted my comment because I can't *downvote* Dan's comment saying the singular is more likely. Google Books [*"attended English class"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22attended+English+class%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):102 hits, [*"attended English **classes**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22attended+English+classes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):3040 hits. I only really mentioned *lessons* to show how unlikely the singular would be there, and I see no reason why *classes* should be any different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Should I therefore say 'he attends gymnastics classes on Mondays'. No! Surely not? There is only one class. So he attends a gymnastics class. I appreciate that I could also say 'he is attending gymnastics classes on Mondays'. But I still think it sort of implies more than one class. There is only one each week.

Comment: @WS2: You'll notice that (a) - your context very specifically applies to a single class, and (b) - you included the article in *"he attends **a** gymnastics class"*. Parents would normally send their children to *a series/complete course of classes*, not just one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think an American student would more likely say she *[went to math class](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+math+class%22&tbm=bks)* than *["went to math classes"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22attended+math+class%22#q=%22went+to+math+classes%22&tbm=bks)*, and Google Books returns 224 for the former and only 2 for the latter. For that matter, if you *skip class*, you may be skipping just one or you may be skipping all of them.

Comment: I'v just found (in Longman) that one meaning of class is: "a series of classes in a particular subject".  so, is **classes** really necessary @FumbleFingers?

Comment: Of course in the UK **lesson** and **course** are much more common than class, I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *et al*. In Britain I agree one would not use *class* without the article. 'She attends a ballet class, on Saturdays' is what we would say. 'She attends ballet class', is undoubtedly American. But we might say 'she attends ballet classes'.

Comment: @alireza: Bear in mind that *your* exact context is relatively uncommon for native speakers, who would normally only think of "English classes" as particular slots in the school timetable. But I'm assuming your context is "extra-curricular" (if "English" was one of the subjects normally taught at your child's school, you wouldn't talk about "sending them to English class/classes/lesson" at all - you'd just be sending them to *school*). To see how *your* context works, check Google Books for *attended/took/went to **piano** XXXX*, where plural (esp ***lessons***) is obviously much more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, I meant ,for example, private classes. thanks a million...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the singular, most listeners would assume that *class* meant a series  sessions rather than just a single session.

Comment: Yes. In the UK, we use the noun to stand metonymically for 'the relevant lesson in ...': _He missed English, science and woodwork!_ and 'the subject / corresponding course in ...': _He' s doing well in French ; _He always has all the answers in science_. Probably 'English class' etc can fulfil similar roles in the US.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth do you mean it is better to say "parents send their children to learn English"?

Comment: @alireza matrix Without more context, the actual preferred choice of words can't be determined. What do you mean by 'Parents send their children to English class'? Parents 'send their children to school' (or should do). The matron might 'send the child back to his English class after bandaging his wrist'. Some parents might 'send their children to English classes' [West Valley City ... [p]rovides transportation when needed to English classes.]

Comment: I mean nowadays,apart from school, parents are more keen to send their children to English private class.

Comment: Ah; we'd almost certainly use 'private classes in English' if using the c-word, but more normal would be 'private English lessons'. 'Private tuition in English' is also used.